# Looking to find a number embedded in a string at some random place - MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I'm converting an old access database to a SQL solution.  There is a comment field that the users used for a six digit number (sometimes).  It is a free-form field and contains things like "ID# 123456", "123456", "ID #123456".  In many cases, however, it just contains random notes that contain some numbers such as dates or other numbers.

What I'd like to do (since this isn't super-critical and is just to get the database started in the direction of properly populating this field), in my select into statement is if there are six consecutive numbers in this comment field insert them into my new field that I'm using specifically for this number.

I've tried various trims and other things but haven't gotten an adequate result.

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Question indicates SQL.

Comment: "SQL" is not a DBMS product. It's a **query language**

Comment: Are you looking for "SQL Server"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

**to select only fields with 6 consecutive digits**

```
select * from LegacyTable
where Comment like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

**To extract those six digits from the string**

```
select Comment
substring(Comment,PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Comment),6) as nbr
from legacytable
where Comment like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Sql Server is your new database, you could try something like this:

```
Select *
From   LegacyTable
-- Where Comment LIKE '%\d\d\d\d\d\d%' This doesn't work
Where Comment Like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

This should return rows that have 6 numbers consecutively in the Comment column.

Comment: Yes Sparky... I knew better than that :( Something like: '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' should work